# How to update XML file through web form using PHP: form name issue

Tags: php, xml, forms

I have done some searching on tis but cannot seem to find any easy way or other examples on the subject (I am new to PHP, XML as of a couple of months ago so bear with me :) ).

- I have an XML file populated with useable data
- I need to be able to load the whole XML file into a form, each child node loading into its own form field
- I want to modify the various fields
- and then save everything back to the same XML file, using PHP to parse the data

PROBLEM : how to label the "names" in the form fields so I know how to populate the proper child nodes. XML file looks like:

```
<band id="1">
 <group>Guns N Roses</group>
 <member>Duff</member>
</band>
<band id="2">
 <group>Iron Maiden</group>
 <member>Paul</member>
</band>
```

To update this through a web form I thought it best to have the name attribute in the INPUT field the same as the child node name.... but then I have would have 2 x groups and 2 members.

Should I somehow append the attribute to the end of the name such that

```
<input name=group.1 value=$group.1>
<input name=group.1 value=$group.2>
```

(where $group.1 and $group.2 can be found using PHP DOM)

and then I have a unique name/value pair in the php $_POST array to use to update the XML file through DOM.

It all just seems very hackish and clunky, and I wonder if there is a more graceful way to do all of this. Again, very new to this... maybe there is already some obvious way to do this that I am completely missing.

Thanks for any help guys

Mr. B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your "XML" is not valid XML. It needs to have a root element that wraps all the content. Right now, you lack this root element because at the top level you have more than one element (......).

So correct this by wrapping your whole string into one other element:

```
$xml = "<root>$xml</root>";
```

Then load it in a DOMDocument element, and traverse and loop through it with DOMXPath or in a simpleXML object (which probably is quicker to code, not sure about performance).

edit: how to name the form elements for an easy update:

```
<input name="band[1][group]" value="$group1">
<input name="band[1][member]" value="$member1" />

<input name="band[2][group]" value="$group1">
<input name="band[2][member]" value="$member1" />
```

After you send the form via post, you can traverse all inputs doing a `foreach` over `$_POST['band']` array:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0)
{
    if (is_array($_POST['band'])
    {
        foreach ($_POST['band'] as $id => $band)
        {
            echo "Band $id has group ".$band['group']." and member ".$band['member']."<br />\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, sorry I left out the root piece accidentially on here. Its really there in the file :) As for the "looping through" I understand about the way to read an XML file in.... but the difficulty is in giving appropriate NAMEs in the web form input fields. From above example I would have 2 MEMBER fields. SO the question is, how do I uniquely label them in a web form and then update the XML accordingly? Thanks

Comment: Oh, didn't understand at first. For the name of the inputs you can create an array, see edit

Comment: Hi Carlo. So, I could replace a few lines in the foreach loop with the necessary XML updates, eg using simpleXML I guess..... I was hoping I had been missing a clean way of doing this (your array suggestion really helps though). Thanks for taking the time and effort to think about my problem and type it up as I really appreciate it! I will post my solution in a bit for others reading this thread. Thanks!! :)

Comment: Hi Morph. Glad you appreciate it. For updating the XML using simpleXML you can look at this page, concretely example 10: http://es2.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php